# Why I get String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error?

Tags: c#, datetime

Trying to parse `s` I get Exception

> "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime"

```
string s = @"07/24/2014 14:46:47";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(s);
```

Comment: Here is the most important question about your question; What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 3):

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider =
   System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateTimeString = @"07/24/2014 14:46:47";
string dateTimeFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTimeString, dateTimeFormat, provider);
```

Useful links:

- [DateTime.ParseExact Method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Standard Date and Time Format Strings on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [The "/" custom format specifier on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)
- [Using the Escape Character on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#escape)

Comment: You should explain why this works. Because `InvariantCulture` forces `/` as date-separator even if the current-culture uses a different separator like `-`. Otherwise `MM/dd/yyyy` would be translated to `MM-dd-yyyy`. To prevent that .NET treats the special `/` character as custom format specifier you either have to use `InvariantCulture`(as mentioned above) or use the escape character: `"MM\/dd\/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`

Comment: @TimSchmelter, Added link to documentation

Answer (score 2):

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("7/24/2014 14:46:47", 
  "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: To add, the documentation contains the following about `DateTime.Parse` - "uses the formatting conventions of the current thread culture and interprets the string based on the DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces style flag"

Comment: Two upvotes? This doesn't work. It uses `-` to parse a string which contains `/`.

Answer (score 0):

As said by Sayse and Sriram Sakthivel you need to pass in the format the string will be in

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```